# Backbone.js model with collection

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have 2 models and one collection. `JobSummary` is a model, `JobSummaryList` is a collection of `JobSummary` items, and then I have a `JobSummarySnapshot` model that contains a `JobSummaryList`:

```
JobSummary = Backbone.Model.extend({});

JobSummaryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: JobSummary
});

JobSummarySnapshot = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/JobSummaryList',

    defaults: {
        pageNumber: 1,
        summaryList: new JobSummaryList()
    }
});
```

When I call `fetch` on the `JobSummarySnapshot` object, it gets everything... Except when I move through the `summaryList` collection they are all of type `object` and not `JobSummary`.

I suppose this makes sense since other than the `defaults` object, it doesn't know that the `summaryList` should be of type `JobSummaryList`. I can go through each item and convert it to a `JobSummary` object, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without having to do it manually.

Here's my test code (working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbfischer/NSEVe/)):

```
var returnData = {
    pageNumber: 3,
    summaryList: [
        {
        id: 5,
        name: 'name1'},
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'name2'}
    ]
}; 

var fakeserver = sinon.fakeServer.create();
fakeserver.respondWith('GET', '/JobSummaryList', [200,
{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                JSON.stringify(returnData)]);

var callback = sinon.spy();


var summarySnapshot = new JobSummarySnapshot();
summarySnapshot.bind('change', callback);

summarySnapshot.fetch();
fakeserver.respond();

var theReturnedList = callback.getCall(0).args[0].attributes.summaryList;

_.each(theReturnedList, function(item) {
    console.log('Original Item: ');
    console.log(item instanceof JobSummary); // IS FALSE
    var convertedItem = new JobSummary(item);
    console.log('converted item: ');
    console.log(convertedItem instanceof JobSummary); // IS TRUE
});
```

UPDATE:
It occurred to me that I could override the parse function and set it that way... I have this now:

```
JobSummarySnapshot = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/JobSummaryList',

    defaults: {
        pageNumber: 1,
        summaryList: new JobSummaryList()
    },

    parse: function(response) {
        this.set({pageNumber: response.pageNumber});

        var summaryList = new JobSummaryList();
        summaryList.add(response.summaryList);

        this.set({summaryList: summaryList});
    }
});
```

This works so far. Leaving the question open in case someone has comment on it....

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your `parse()` function shouldn't `set()` anything, its a better practice to just return the attributes, Backbone will take care of setting it. e.g.

```
parse: function(response) {
    response.summaryList = new JobSummaryList(response.summaryList);
    return response;
}
```

Whatever you return from `parse()` is [passed to `set()`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L284).

Not returning anything (which is like returning `undefined`) is the same as calling `set(undefined)`, which could cause it not to pass validation, or some other unexpected results if your custom `validate()`/`set()` methods expects to get an object. If your validation or `set()` method fails because of that, the `options.success` callback passed to `Backbone.Model#fetch()` won't be called.

Also, to make this more generic, so that `set()`ing to a plain object from other places (and not only from the server response) also effects it, you might want to override `set()` instead:

```
set: function(attributes, options) {
    if (attributes.summaryList !== undefined && !(attributes.summaryList instanceof JobSummaryList)) {
        attributes.summaryList = new JobSummaryList(attributes.summaryList);
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
}
```

You might also find [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) interesting - it makes it much easier to deal with collections/models nested inside models.

**edit** I forgot to return from the set() method, the code is now updated

Comment: thank you very much. I've been guilty of only half reading things today and once again, it bit me. It clearly says in the docs that, as you mention above, you return the obj from the parse function.... But I somehow missed that. Thanks again.