# Backbone.js architecture: collections vs javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I will start soon to develop my first application that uses Backbone. Looking a lot of tutorials, but can't decide how to architecture my app, since it's slightly different than the typical single-model CRUD example. Here is the deal:

My app will basically be an Atlas of ants. So basically, the user select an ant species, optionally add filters and then will be shown a Leaflet.js map and an spreadsheet-like table of results. We'll also need to accumulate several search results on the page (for example to compare geographic distribution of different species).

I envisioned two options there:

A) Either the (Backbone) model is the ant occurrence, and each user search is a different Backbone collection, containing matching occurrences and a few search-level properties. This makes sense, since the server-side model will also be the ant occurrence, and I'll then be able to take full advantage of automatic REST integration. But I'll have to use a JavaScript array to keep track of these different collections. Events will also have to be managed on these collections, for example when the user want to remove a previous search from the displayed data.

B) Either the model is a "search" object, and these various accumulated searches are kept in a collection. I can then take full advantage of these collections, but client/server models will not be the same thing (searches vs occurrences), so I won't be able to use a simple RESTful approach there.

What would you choose ?

Thanks, Nicolas

Comment: It sounds like you need to try something, anything, and come back when you have technical trouble. There is no better way to learn than to try - especially when designing architectures.

Comment: Thanks ! Sure I'll do, I was just thinking that I may receive good advices before. In the meantime I also found an interesting approach (Model containing Collection) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140741/backbone-js-model-with-collection so I think I'll try this first and see !

Answer (score 0):

I find it confusing when I have to figure out whether something is a Collection or an array, so I pick one and stick with it. You get more functionality out of Backbone Collections, so I choose those for everything and avoid arrays.