# Is it a good idea to put different types of models in a backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My app has a few different models to keep track of. I was wondering if I could put them in a collection so they could bubble events to one place. Is this a good idea or should I not put different types of models in the same collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have multiple types in 1 collection
though it would be best if you make some adjustments depending on how you are going to add these models into your collection.

the people on this stack overflow question were already suggesting to override certain key functions in the collection object, like the parse method for example

check out more on this link: [Backbone.Js Collection with Specific Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061445/backbone-js-collection-with-specific-types)

I think your case is a little different, and in your case I would check out if it was feasable to just use a global array in my application object instead.